# if the code in C# dll is running?

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection, clr, difference

I know the CLR would optimize some codes, but I don't know what are they, like the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string another = "a";
            var no = p.SNo;
            var field = p.FieldA;
            string name = "stackoverflow" + p.Name;
            var a = p.Name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("yes, clr runs it");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("over");
    }

    public string FieldA;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return GetName();
        }
    }

    public string SNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        throw new Exception("can you run at here?");
    }
}
```

environment: .net 4.0 + vs2015 + win7x64
output in debug mode(it run`string another = "a";`):

> yes, clr runs it
>
> over

output in release mode(the same as debug mode), and it has the 'Optimize code' flag:

> yes, clr runs it
>
> over

then I find the code in dll:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        string sNo = program.SNo;
        string fieldA = program.FieldA;
        string text3 = "stackoverflow" + program.Name;
        string name = program.Name;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("yes, clr runs it");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("over");
}
```

the `string another = "a";` has disappeared, but the property `program.SNo` and the field `program.FieldA` and the nonuse `text3` are there.

So, what has the `clr` done? and will it be different when it become an aps.net application running in the IIS? has the IIS done something?

Answer (score 1):

Removal of dead code, including unused variables, is one of the most basic optimizations any compiler does. Code analysis raises a warning for this: [CA1804: Remove unused locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182278.aspx) and it very explicitly states:

> Note that the C# compiler [...] **removes unused local variables when the optimize option is enabled**.

Comment: thank you first, but program.SNo and program.FieldA are also not used, why they are in the dll? if the code in dll is the real code to be running?

Comment: Because those are not locals. Unused locals are guaranteed to be unreachable, but unused fields inside a DLL may well be consumed by another app referencing this dll of yours. No offense, but you are barely skimming the surface of a huge body of knowledge that I feel you are yet to master. You can read and learn plenty about compiler optimization. Here is something short to wet your appetite: [What does the optimize switch do?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/)

Comment: thanks again, I read that articel and know why it do as this a little, now my question are: 
1:are there only clr compile and jitter to optimize?
2:if 1 is true, there is no way to find out what it is real running code?
I am wondering how my programe works.